# What is the impact of not calling the arguments while calling a function

Tags: r

My question is about the difference between two ways to pass the the arguments of a function

for instance

```
function1(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5)
```

or

```
function1(arg1=obj1, arg2=obj2, arg3=obj3, arg4=obj4, arg5=obj5)
```

Is there a rule/convention/document for that?

I can see at least 2 situations where the first way is not great

1. If we want to add a new argument, we are forced to add it at the end of the list, which may not great for the common sense (as I like to group arguments that goes together)
2. The arguments with default have to be put at the end of the list, otherwise you have to input it even if you use the default value.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Before this question is inevitably closed as a poll, I'll point out that it would be silly, IMHO, to think that the only possible styles are (a) to never name arguments or (b) always name arguments. You can do both.

Comment: my question is about the pros and cons, or when we can safely not use name arguments

Comment: Why is this question not eligible?

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time convincing folks that asking about pros and cons doesn't fall under "opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". Don't get me wrong, I stared at this question for several minutes trying to think of a way to salvage it. The R chat room (at a better time of day when folks are around) would probably be a good place to ask this.

Comment: Well I disagree with you. Pros and cons can be very scientific and rationale. While using something we have to know what we do and the impact. This question is not at all about opinions but about facts. Do you really understand the question??

Comment: No need to get upset! I'm not saying it's a bad question. I'm just saying that based on my experience about what the SO community, as a group, decides is a poll, that this likely will fit that description.

Comment: Check out this on R's flexible argument binding: http://blog.moertel.com/articles/2006/01/20/wondrous-oddities-rs-function-call-semantics

Comment: Not sure who's voting to close, but dropping the `argument-passing` tag may help this question fly under the radar a bit more as it's less likely to attract SO closing zealots. Good question IMHO.

Comment: I think this is a valid question for typical R users and developers.  Just because others on SO don't appreciate/understand the basis for *some* R questions doesn't mean that people who understand R need to perpetuate that misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the issue is simple: reproducible results require reproducible and explicit function calls.

In my case, I use named arguments having learned that another person may insert a new parameter in their function if they so choose, which caused my code to break.

I also tend to store parameters in a list and use these when calling a function, e.g. `someCrazyFunction(stuff = stuff, eps = Par$eps, tol = Par$tol, verbose = Par$verbose, strict = Par$strict, debug = Par$debug)`

If I don't do this, I am not doing my part to ensure reproducible results.  It is only a few keystrokes and I don't have to worry if the author of the function or package moves arguments around, inserts new arguments, deletes some arguments (which I'll notice because R will tell me that some object is not needed), or otherwise makes seemingly harmless changes.  If they make such a change, then how can someone else who looks at my code be sure of how to reproduce the same call as it was at the time I made it?

Lesson: Debugging is far more painful than the few keystrokes needed to ensure reproducibility.

---

(Minor update) [This question & the selected answer from elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427962/is-you-break-it-you-buy-it-the-best-policy) exemplifies a particular aspect of this implicit contract between the package creator and the person with a dependency on a package.  If I develop a dependency on a given function and the author simply shuffles the arguments, then my code should work perfectly regardless.  They made no explicit contract to not move things around, and I can assume no implicit contract that it will behave that way.  I only assume that they will not change the definitions of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

From a function implementer's point of view, you must always add new parameters to the end and name them so they don't have a prefix in common with existing arguments.

This is because people are free to use positional matching and partial names. A fact of R life...

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments in R can be matched via position or by name and you as the person punching things into the keyboard are afforded some flexibility in how you decide to use or abuse that. One of the immediate benefits to using the named arguments is that you can change the order of the arguments within the function as you see fit. i.e.

```
function1(arg1=obj1, arg2=obj2, arg3=obj3, arg4=obj4, arg5=obj5)
```

and

```
function1(arg5=obj5, arg4=obj4, arg3=obj3, arg2=obj2, arg1=obj1)
```

will evaluate in the same fashion, while

```
function1(obj1, aobj2, obj3, obj4, obj5)
```

and

```
function1(obj5, aobj4, obj3, obj2, obj1)
```

will not. Function arguments can also be partially matched and are matched using the following criteria:

1. exact match for named argument
2. partial match for named argument
3. positional match

This can obviously lead to some unintended consequences if you aren't careful with the partial matching. I believe that if an argument is matched by name, it is "removed" from the positional search, though I can't find a specific reference for that at the moment. As a note of common use, I tend to see people use the positional matching for the first argument in a function, and then specify others that may be optional afterwords by name. Again, this is mostly personal convention and habit as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Actually if you define the argument list like (x,y,z) then calling with (z=3, y=10, x=30) will get the correct assignments to those argument and not result in positional matching. You gave the answer I was going to give, but when I tested it. my poor understanding "turned to dust".

Answer (score 0):

In functional programming like R, there can be thirty or something parameters for a function. In that case, argument names are handy with default parameter values.

Other than that, especially for short list of parameters, argument names do not make good sense.